# In keyboard app, I want to return to my keyboard app after changing another

Tags: android, keyboard

I create a keyboard app.

It changes to another by the functionality when it is fulfilled with specific situation.

This method is that `switchInputMethod()` which inherits `InputMethodService` class. And I tried to change the keyboard temporary.

However, when I call `switchInputMethod()`, it behaves as changing “Default” App of Android device.

After that, I can’t show my keyboard app.

In this case, I reselect “Default” of “language ant input” from “Setting” in my device.

I’d like to realize the following.

There is Activity has `EditText1`, `EditText2` and `EditText3`.
In the case of `EditText1` and `EditText3`, I input with my keyboard app.
And `EditText2`, I do with another.

[[add image]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its your app that's running, you can override the default input method for a given field via android:inputMethod in xml on the TextView or setInputMethod in Java.  Then it would use that input method for the TextView and return to default for others.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.<br/>
Use this keyboard app is my app.<br/>
Do I have the right to specify what to <code>inputText</code> of <code>EditText</code>?<br/>

<code>Package name</code> of the keyboard app? Or the name of the class inherits the <code>InputMethodService</code> in the keyboard app?

Comment: From the docs:  If set, specifies that this TextView should use the specified input method (specified by fully-qualified class name).

Must be a string value, using '\\;' to escape characters such as '\\n' or '\\uxxxx' for a unicode character.

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

Comment: I herad at some where,
Due to security reasons android doesn't allows application to change the inputMethod type.
I draw image, that I want to do.

Comment: It doesn't let you change the default input method for all apps. You can change it for your app

Comment: I can not understand. Is that specified in the fully qualified class name.
What it should be I specify what. To android:inputMethod.